# What aspect of elliptic curve encryption paradigms makes them especially susceptible to quantum based attack algorithms?

Tags: elliptic-curves, post-quantum-cryptography, attack

This was a statement made during a talk at today's DFN-CERT conference but unfortunately it wasn't explained further. Can anyone shed light on why elliptic curves are susceptible to quantum based attacks ?

Comment: The discrete logarithm problem in any cyclic group is easy to solve by quantum algorithms. Elliptic curves merely give a particular choice of cyclic group.  Solving the discrete log problem is enough to break all elliptic curve cryptosystems.

Comment: Do you have source for this?

Answer (score 3):

The elliptic curve discrete logarithm—like integer factorization and the classic finite field discrete logarithm—is an instance of the abelian [hidden subgroup problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_subgroup_problem).

Any abelian (commutative) instance of the hidden subgroup problem can be efficiently solved in quantum computers with (variants of) the [Shor algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shor%27s_algorithm); therefore all of the above problems would be rendered weak if large enough quantum computers were actually built. [Here](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0301141) is a concrete polynomial-time quantum attack  for the elliptic curve discrete logarithm. See also [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/248/what-exactly-is-the-impact-of-the-hidden-subgroup-problem-on-cryptography).