# Understanding the Hidden Subgroup Problem specific to Integer Factorization

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography, factoring, group-theory

I've been reading about the Hidden Subgroup Problem (HSP), specifically trying to understand how it is related to the integer factorization problem. I've read [What exactly is the impact of the hidden subgroup problem on cryptography?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/248/what-exactly-is-the-impact-of-the-hidden-subgroup-problem-on-cryptography) but it doesn't cover the specifics I am having trouble putting together.

To define the HSP:

> Given a group $G$, a subgroup $H \leq G$, and a set $X$, we say a function $f : G \Rightarrow X$ separates cosets of $H$ if for all $g_1, g_2 \in G$, $f(g_1) = f(g_2)$ if and only if $g_1H = g_2H$.
>
> Hidden subgroup problem: Let $G$ be a group, $X$ a finite set, and $f : G \Rightarrow X$ a function such that there exists a subgroup $H \leq G$ for which $f$ separates cosets of $H$. The function $f$ is given via an oracle. Using information gained from evaluations of $f$ via its oracle, determine a generating set for $H$.

What I can't figure out is how to reduce the integer factorization problem to an HSP problem, and then why the (abelian) HSP problem is not solvable in polynomial time without a quantum computer using e.g. Shor's algorithm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $\mathbb{Z}, +$ be the group integers, $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}, \times$ the multiplicative group of integers modulo $n$, and $\varphi(n)$ its order. Then $\varphi(n)\mathbb{Z}, +$, the additive group of multiples of $\varphi(n)$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$. The function $f : \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} : x \mapsto a^x \mod n$ for fixed $a \in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ satisfies the description of the HSP oracle for the subgroup $H=\varphi(n)\mathbb{Z}$ of $\mathbb{Z}$ because

$\phantom{\Leftrightarrow} \forall \, x, y \in \mathbb{Z} \, . \, f(x) = f(y) \\
\Leftrightarrow x = y \mod \varphi(n) \\
\Leftrightarrow x = y + k\varphi(n) \quad \mathit{for \, some} \quad k \in \mathbb{Z} \\
\Leftrightarrow x = y + H$

Consequently, the formulation of the factorization problem is to find a generator of the group $\varphi(n)\mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{Z}$ given access to the function $f$ that computes exponentiation modulo $n$. Once you have this generator, $\varphi(n)$, computing the factorization of $n$ is easy using some straightforward (classical) number theory.